# Trying to use puppeteer plugin but I keep getting an error for Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, puppeteer, require

my program is supposed to search a website named suplexed.com, for a given sneaker code, and return the price of the smallest size available for a given sneaker. When I run the individual .js file in the console using node I do get the value I'm looking for. However, when I run HTML file that is supposed to use the .js file I get the following error

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

here is my javascript code-named "scrapers.js". I added comments for better understanding. When running the .js file in the console using node there are no problems. But when running the directory using live-server through HTML it doesn't work. The problem here lies in the first few lines of code as it won't go past there

```
async function scrapeStockx(url){
  const site = "stockx.com";
  let puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
  let pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
  puppeteer.use(pluginStealth());

  puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
  
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url,{waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});


  // get the value for the row sneaker size for stockx
  await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="pricer_table"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]');
  const [sneakerSize]= await page.$x('//*[@id="pricer_table"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]');
  
  const sneakerSizeTxt = await sneakerSize.getProperty('textContent');
  const sneakerSizeRawTxt = await sneakerSizeTxt.jsonValue(); 


  // get the value for the row sneaker size price for stockx
  await page.waitForXPath('//*[@id="pricer_table"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span[1]');
  const [sneakerPrice]= await page.$x('//*[@id="pricer_table"]/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span[1]');
   
  const sneakerPriceTxt = await sneakerPrice.getProperty('textContent');
  const sneakerPriceRawTxt = await sneakerPriceTxt.jsonValue(); 
  
  // print the sneaker size and price to verify TO CONSOLE
  console.log(printSizeAndPrices(sneakerSizeRawTxt, sneakerPriceRawTxt, site)); 

  // print the sneaker size and price TO WEBSITE
  let sneakerPrint = document.createElement("p");
  sneakerPrint.textContent = printSizeAndPrice(sneakerPriceRawTxt, sneakerPriceRawTxt, site)
  document.querySelector("body").appendChild(sneakerPrint);

  browser.close();
}

document.querySelector("#search-form").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault()

  // get sneaker code using the textbox created in html
  // const sneakerCode = e.target.elements.enterBox.value
  
  // manually enter a unique sneaker code
  const sneakerCode = "XXXXXX-XXX";

  // print sneaker code to console to verify
  console.log("sneakerCode: " + sneakerCode)
 
  // create the website address of the sneaker
  const address = ('https://suplexed.com/web/' + sneakerCode)

  // print website address to verify
  console.log("address: " + address)

  // call the function to retrieve the wanted values for the chosen sneaker
  scrapeStockx(address)
})

function printSizeAndPrice(sneakerSizeRawTxt, sneakerPriceRawTxt, site){
  return `${sneakerSizeRawTxt} is ${sneakerPriceRawTxt} on ${site}`;
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Enter a sneaker code and hit the button to search</p>

        <form id = "search-form">
            <input type = "text" placeholder = "XXXXXX-XXX" name = "enterBox">
            <button>Search</button>
        </form>

        <script src = "scrapers.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: puppeteer won't run in a browser, it's a node library.

Comment: @pguardiario do you have any alternatives for web scraping then?

Comment: You want to submit the code to the backend (express?) and scrape it there.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete solution to the problem, but it did bring me to a new error to which I am now researching. In my index.html file I simply added a script tag right before my main js tag that included the require.js file

```
<script src = "require.js"></script>
```